# Working with JSON Arrays

Tags: android

http://pastie.org/8269975 . If you look at my code, i don't know how to access the individual fields like account_id, hero_id, and etc. I have this code.

```
JSONObject match = getMatchDetails("281699681");
```

if i want to access those individual fields like account_id, then this code is not working.

```
int a = match.result.players[0].account_id;
```

please help me and if you want to look at the JSON script, here's the link
https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id=281699681&key=8F48DE9EBF9C9EA121A6A9EF2E30B7C7

Answer (score 1):

JSON uses JavaScript Objects, not Java objects and hence you cannot directly access members as if they were Java objects. You need something like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert between JSON representation and Java object representation.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This method to iterate any json object dynamically.**

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject data) {

        if (data != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = data.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();

                try {
                    if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        JSONArray arry = data.getJSONArray(key);
                        int size = arry.length();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            parseJson(arry.getJSONObject(i));
                        }
                    } else if (data.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        parseJson(data.getJSONObject(key));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("" + key + " : " + data.optString(key));
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("" + key + " : " + data.optString(key));
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: err, i do not get it sir. will that parseJson() function will give me the individual fields of the player[0] object ?

Comment: had you try this function? it will print all keys and value.

Comment: uhm sir, i need to know the individual values, because i will associate it to some pictures and other media.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try replacing the line,

```
    String MatchDetailsURL = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id"+ matchID + "=&key=" + SteamWebAPIKey;
```

with,

```
    String MatchDetailsURL = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id="+ matchID + "&key=" + SteamWebAPIKey;
```

in your code and try.

Bcs, instead of giving `match_id="+ matchID + "&key` you have given `match_id"+ matchID + "=&key`..So, the URL itself is wrong and it returns a bad request..

Comment: it helped me, but it doesn't answer my question